# Why is Winver showing another Version than Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, windowsversion

[image: Winver VS Powershell Output]

Hello Guys! Why is Winver showing me Windows Version 21H2 but Powershell Command 2009?

`Get-ComputerInfo | select WindowsProductName, WindowsVersion`

Info: With my Personal PC at home Windows 11 Pro 21H2, it works with the command

`Get-ComputerInfo | Select-Object -expand OSDisplayVersion`

Unfortunately this Property doesn`t exist at my Laptop, or maybe in general at Win10 Enterprise?

Comment: Do you have some Powershell code that depends on the newer version? Please post your code...

Answer (score 3):

You can mimic the way winver.exe shows the current Windows version by taking the values from the registry:

```
$v = Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion'
# output like winver does
'Version {0} (Build {1}.{2})' -f $v.DisplayVersion, $v.CurrentBuildNumber, $v.UBR
```

Output:

```
Version 21H2 (Build 19044.1645)
```

<sup>`UBR` means `Update Build Revision`</sup>

Comment: Looking in the `C:\Windows\servicing\Packages` directory, the most recent `*.mum` files are showing `10.0.19041.2311`, but your script above shows `19044.2364`. What's going on?