# How to get windows version output from Powershell with the same output I get from running winver

Tags: powershell, windows-10-desktop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAjla.png)

I'm looking to have the build version listed out as it is shown there. I've ran every powershell command from the following

[How to find the Windows version from the PowerShell command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330187/how-to-find-the-windows-version-from-the-powershell-command-line)

The closest to the output is `Get-ComputerInfo | select WindowsProductName, WindowsVersion, OsHardwareAbstractionLayer`

However, it is not giving me the minor version as it is listed with the winver command. winver lists:`Build 19045.4170` but that command outputs `10.0.19041.3636`

Does anyone know a command which will output the same values as winver?

Answer (score 0):

After way to much digging I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72123113/why-is-winver-showing-another-version-than-powershell)

The quick answer is the following copy and pasted into Powershell

```
$v = Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion'
# output like winver does
'Version {0} (Build {1}.{2})' -f $v.DisplayVersion, $v.CurrentBuildNumber, $v.UBR
```